# Upper bound for recursion?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, inequality, arithmetic, recreational-mathematics, arithmetic-progressions

Consider $$\frac1{k!}\prod_{j=1}^k(\ell+j)>n$$

Does $\ell\leq 2kn^{1/k}$ suffice ( above gives $\ell>c\cdot kn^{1/k}$ necessary at some $c>0$)?

Is there a tighter bound?

Is there any interpretation of this value?

Comment: What is $i$? You index everything with $j$ by the way! And where is recursion?

Comment: ? That expression is just $\frac{(\ell-i)^k}{k!}$?

Comment: Shouldn't it be $\ell\geq 2kn^{1/k}$?

Comment: It doesn't make sense, for example, take $\ell=k+1<2k\sqrt[k]{n}$ then $\frac{1}{k!}\prod\limits_{j=1}^{k}(\ell-j)=1 < n$.